# How do I package an HTML5 web app as an Android app?

Tags: html, web-applications, package

I have been searching the Internet for hours and I still have no idea what it is or what to do - I was assigned this task by my boss.

Please somebody just give me a step-by-step guide on what to do. I can look up the individual steps on my own; I just need to know the process.

And please don't post links; I have been doing that for the past hour and I just need someone to give me a brief outline (kind of like what Wikihow or eHow does).

Thank you.

Comment: I have downloaded Cordova, Phonegap, and the Android SDK, and have been trying to follow the instructions on their websites to set each up. Most of the times, there has been an error in the installation and I would get stuck for a bit trying to figure out what went wrong there. 

In addition, I have spent a large amount of time searching keywords on my topic, and reading questions and answers about others who had similar issues.

Comment: But I think I figured out a list of steps. Can you tell me if this is correct?

1. Zip the entire web app into a package.
2. Use the Android SDK to convert the package into a .apk file.
3. Unzip the .apk file on a mobile device to be able to run the app on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is all in HTML, you can use a framework such as [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) (formerly known as *PhoneGap*) to package it into an Android app.

There are instructions on the official website on how to do that: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide